# Why does a curve connecting a node from a column to another node in another column disappear?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, pst-node

I want to show items, each with a curve pointing to a point on the right figure. But in the following code, the curves disappear. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}}

\psset{xunit=.1\wd\IBox,yunit=.1\ht\IBox,arrows=->,linecolor=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Hello World and Hello Universe}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2-> \rnode[r]{HWl}{Hello World}\nccurve{HWl}{HWr}
        \item<3-> \rnode[r]{HUl}{Hello Universe}\nccurve{HUl}{HUr}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.7\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](10,10)
        \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
        \pnode(2,4){HWr}
        \pnode(5,8){HUr}
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes `HWr` and `HUr` are defined only after you `\nccurve` commands. You can add e.g.

```
\only<2>{\nccurve{HWl}{HWr}}
\only<3>{\nccurve{HUl}{HUr}}
```

after you defined all nodes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}}

\psset{xunit=.1\wd\IBox,yunit=.1\ht\IBox,arrows=->,linecolor=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Hello World and Hello Universe}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2-> \rnode[r]{HWl}{Hello World}\nccurve{HWl}{HWr}
        \item<3-> \rnode[r]{HUl}{Hello Universe}\nccurve{HUl}{HUr}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.7\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](10,10)
        \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
        \pnode(2,4){HWr}
        \pnode(5,8){HUr}
        \only<2>{\nccurve{HWl}{HWr}}
        \only<3>{\nccurve{HUl}{HUr}}
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```